# GEE Combined with Linear Mixed Model

Tags: interpretation, mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations

Suppose we have a linear mixed model with outcome variable $Y_{ij}$ and covariate $X_{ij}$. In particular, suppose we have a random intercept model:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{ij}|b_i, X_{ij}] = \beta_0+b_i+ \beta_{1}X_{ij}$$
$$ b_{i} \sim N(0, \sigma_{b}^{2})$$
$$ e_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma_{Y}^{2})$$

If we run a GEE linear regression model with an exchangeable correlation matrix, could we still include $b_i$ in the mean model? Or would we have to get rid of the $b_i$ and the normality assumptions?

Also suppose $X_{ij}$ is sex ($1$ for male, $0$ for female). Let $b_i$ be random intercepts for people. For an interpretation of $\beta_1$, could we say: For any person, being male is associated with an average increase of $\beta_1$ units in $Y_{ij}$ compared to being female? A person can't be male and then become female.

Comment: I think you're right that you lose $b_i$ when you do GEE. GEE in a sense averages over the individuals, whereas a mixed effect analyses models the variation between individuals.